# Transform every two fields of rows into columns containing two rows

Tags: python, loops, rows

I would like to transform every two fields of rows into columns containing two rows. And loop this transformation for each row

This is the input:

```
id  refpop001   altpop001   refpop002   altpop002   refpop003   altpop003
id1 6   274 2   93  5   95
id2 202 0   220 0   73  0
id3 166 159 0   173 114 90
```

This is the desired output:

```
id  pop001  pop002  pop003
id1ref  6   2   5
id1alt  274 93  95
id2ref  202 220 73
id2alt  0   0   0
id3ref  166 0   114
id3alt  159 173 90
```

Header and id column are only indicated for clarification and are not required in the output

Comment: Plese [edit] your question and show us what you have tried.

Comment: What is this? a text file? a pandas' DataFrame? a bunch of variables? And what output do you want? a file? ... you see where I'm going with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you are transforming tab delimited plain text which is in file and your data size is not changing, straightforward approach is:

```
lines=open('file_or_stream_name.txt','r').readlines();

newLines=[]
newLines.append('\t'.join('id','pop001','pop002','pop003')) #header line
for line in lines[1:]:
    elements=line.split('\t')
    newLine=[]
    newLine.append(elements[0]+'ref')
    newLine.extend(elements[1::2])
    newLines.append('\t'.join(newLine))

    newLine=[]
    newLine.append(elements[0]+'alt')
    newLine.extend(elements[2::2])
    newLines.append('\t'.join(newLine))

newText='\n'.join(newLines) #or '\r\n'.join(...), if you're in Windows
```

Comment: I would go with this code lol.  I kind of gave more of an over arching idea on how to do it rather than an implementation

Comment: Fixed some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the input and then split it up, maybe something along the lines of this

```
int i = 0
for row in input:
  row_array = row.split()
  i = i+=1
  ref = row_array[0] + " " + row_array[2] + " " + row_array[4]]
  alt = row_array[1] + " " +  row_array[3] + " " + row_array[5]

  print "id" + i +"ref " + ref
  print "id" + i + "alt" + alt
```

Didn't actually run this code, but the idea is there so manipulate this as necessary.